# Sampling Distribution of $X_{(n)}$ $-$ $Y_{(1)}$ when $X$ and $Y$ are correlated

Tags: bootstrap

Consider two dependent (correlated) random variables $X$ and $Y$. Both $X$ and $Y$ have support in the closed interval [0, 1]. Further $X$ $\geq$ $Y$ and $X \geq 0, Y \geq 0$.

This is not a homework or self-study question, so no information on the joint pdf is given. However, I might reasonably guess from the stated restriction that $f(x, y) = x - y$ would be a good choice.

Hence, $\int^0_1 \int^0_1 (x - y) dy dx = 0$

I am looking to obtain the approximate sampling distribution of $X_{(n)}$ $-$ $Y_{(1)}$, *i.e.*, the maximum of $X$ minus the minimum of $Y$.

The reasoning behind all of this is to be able to compute appropriate level confidence intervals for the parameter of interest based on a statistic calculated from sample data.

To me, this question is analogous to the sampling distribution of a sort of sample range, except the extreme values are drawn from different datasets.

While there is some information on Wikipedia regarding the distribution of the range, it applies to only a single dataset.

Employing the nonparametric bootstrap seems pointless, since it can often fail for extreme order statistics.

**ASIDE (providing a bit of context)**

In my case, $X$ and $Y$ are pairwise distances between sampled observations, say Euclidean (I don't think it actually matters).

Clearly, dist($i$, $j$) = dist($j$, $i$), that is, the corresponding distance matrix is symmetric about the main diagonal.

Hence, there is a need to state that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent of one another.

Comment: Please describe what information you have about the joint distribution of $(X,Y).$  "Correlated" isn't enough to provide an answer: how exactly are these variables related? Do you need a calculation or an estimate from data or something else?

Comment: I don't see why the correlation matters. Let $X = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $Y = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Then $X_{(n)} - Y_{(1)} = 4$. Now remove the correlation to give $X = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $Y = \{5,1,4,2,3\}$. Still $X_{(n)} - Y_{(1)} = 4$.

Comment: @Dave I suppose it wouldn't in the case you describe

Comment: @Dave Although the *statistic* doesn't depend on the association of $X$ and $Y,$ certainly its *sampling distribution* depends on the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$!

Comment: @whuber I’m going to run an R simulation tonight and bootstrap the bivariate distributions in my previous comment. I’m curious what will happen, because it’s not at all obvious to me why the order of $Y$ matters. I’ll report back with my findings.

Comment: @Dave That's scarcely needed.  Consider, for instance, marginal uniform distributions and samples of size $1.$  When the marginals are independent, $X_{n}-Y_{1}$ has a distribution of mean $0$ and variance $1/6.$  In the extreme case where $Y=X$ (perfect correlation), $X_{n}-Y_{1}$ is constantly zero: obviously these are different sampling distributions. The calculations for larger $n$ are not much harder and also provide counterexamples.

Comment: What I’m finding in my simulation is that, when there’s positive correlation, the big values tend to be matched with other big values, so when big $X$ values are excluded, that lowers $X_{(n)}$ but doesn’t have much impact on $Y_{(1)}$. However, when there is no correlation, all bets are off on what gets excluded when big $X$ values are excluded, hence a different sampling distribution.